# STM32H743 with USB HS, FUSB2805 not detected

Tags: usb, stm32, high-speed, stm32cubemx, stm32h

I have a custom board with STM32H743VIT6 connected to an external USB HS PHY, the FUSB2805MLX.

I am trying to run a bare minimum example setup in STM32CubeMx. Just including a USB HS connection and the device in USB VCP mode.
The pin setup is correct, and the external clocks on the PHY are correct (26MHz in, generates 60MHz on CLK line between MCU and PHY).

I can see that the 60Mhz line is shut down after the call to `USBD_Start(&hUsbDeviceHs)`
The data lines are pulled high at the same time.

The relevant pinout is:

```
PA3 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_DO  
PA5 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_CK  
PB0 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_D1  
PB1 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_D2  
PB5 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_D7  
PB10 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_D3  
PB11 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_D4  
PB12 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_D5  
PB13 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_D6  
PC0 -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_STP  
PC2_C -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_DIR  
PC3_C -> USB_OTG_HS_ULPI_NXT
```

However, i cannot get this to work.
The code runs without errors and debugging through it doesn't give me any idea of what might be wrong. All functions return with HAL_OK

The computer does not detect the USB device.

`sudo dmesg | grep usb` gives the following output

```
    [27482.966148] usb usb3-port7: attempt power cycle
    [27483.622018] usb 3-7: new low-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
    [27483.622532] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
    [27483.830337] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
    [27484.041933] usb 3-7: device not accepting address 32, error -71
    [27484.173925] usb 3-7: new low-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
    [27484.174414] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
    [27484.382364] usb 3-7: Device not responding to setup address.
    [27484.589893] usb 3-7: device not accepting address 33, error -71
    [27484.590002] usb usb3-port7: unable to enumerate USB device
    [81863.025532] usb 3-3: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
    [82185.873876] usb 3-3: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
    [82306.336339] usb 3-3: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
    [82758.471075] usb 3-3: reset full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
```

It's the same using the USB_DEVICE Middleware in Mass Storace Class mode.
Are there any tricks to getting ULPI USB HS to work on this MCU?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have similar now.

Comment: Ditto! Actually my device is recognized but other than that no data is transferred! @MarkKCowan did you ever solve it?

Comment: I solved it, I changed some setting in STM32CubeMX regarding USB (ep1 interrupt I think), and that fixed it.

For the higher-level part of the stack, I use tinyUSB instead of ST's drivers.